# delete points in a vector layer

Tags: qgis, editing, filter

I have a vector layer in QGIS with 30000 points. I want to delete those with values lower than a specific value. I could not use filter in an edited layer, and I could not filter the layer after editing it.

What can I do?

Comment: You are probably working with shapefiles. Save your data to spatialite, and editing **and** filtering is possible.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but still can not edit and filtering at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by open attribute, then click 'select features using an expression' and then write down 'YOUR_VALUE_FIELD' < "YOUR_OPTIONAL_NUMBER". as the picture below :

[image: instruction]

if your field is a string type, you must change it to integers by doing the following :

- ctrl + I
- Create new field
- `to_int('YOUR_STRING_FIELD')`

then it's good to go...

Comment: I assumed the user is new to Qgis... if  not, try AndreJ solution...

Comment: I do not understand, Select by expression does not work either. I can choose the criteria, but it does not select the points. What I did was filter, copy and paste the filtered points to a new layer. Thanks.

Comment: I had some experience working with Esri's geodatabase files which couldn't be edited. I must export them in one of the supported files and then edit the exported.

Comment: I have to say the most compatible extension for Qgis is the spatialite database and files. many tutorials are available on the net. remember creating a spatial index for each layer. This makes all tools operate fine without any errors.